# Where should i start with Google Apps APIs?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

I have a subject, where i need to study about Google Apps APIs, and apply them on web applications.
But I have never learned about the APIs before, it's really hard to say where should I start.

Do i need to use Google Apps first? 
What is the relationship between Google Apps and Google App Engine? 
What is the better way to use Google apps APIs on my web application?
And last is which language should I use, java or Php? I don't know python though.

Can anyone please enlighten me on those question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google App Engine is a PaaS (Platform as a service) where people can deploy their applications and scale with Cloud infrastructure. The only supported languages as of now are Java, Python and Go. PHP is not officially supported, but can be used with some hacks.

Google Apps are like standard apps which are developed by people/community and are available to purchase. The apps are very much like apps on your smartphone, purchase what you need. Google Apps APIs allow people to write such apps and sell them on Google Apps Market place.

I would suggest start with a small tutorial on GAE and then understand Google Apps and APIs better. But for sake of simplicity you can simply leave out GAE and understand APIs and Google Apps.

Some tutorials on GAE are available [here](http://cloudspring.com/author/vbiyani/)

You can start with Google Apps APIs [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/app-apis)

You can start a free trial of Google apps with your Google ID and add some apps to your hypothetical company [here](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good starting point: [Web Application Engineering](http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs253/CourseRev/apr2012)